# Format a division as a percent with decimal places

Tags: postgresql

I'm finding this surprisingly difficult.

```
select 10 / 100 as ten_pct
```

Returns just 0.

I want 0.1. Tried:

```
select round(10 / 100, 2) as ten_pct
```

Also returns 0.

```
select (10 / 100)::float as ten_pct
```

Also returns 0

```
select (10 / 100)::decimal as ten_pct
```

Also returns 0

How can I return 0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`10 / 100` is an integer division and returns an integer. You need to make at least one number a decimal *before* you divide them

`10.0 / 100` or `10 / 100::decimal` or `10 / 100.0`